# How Can I Swap Map Elements without Moving?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, swap, c++03

If I have two `map<string, int>`s how can I swap an element from each `map`?

For example:

```
map<string, int> ps{ { "triangle", 0 }, { "cross", 1 }, { "square", 2 }, { "circle", 3 } };
map<string, int> xbox{ { "y", 0 }, { "a", 1 }, { "b", 2 }, { "x", 3 } };

swap(move(ps["cross"]), move(xbox["x"]));
```

The `swap` statement is clearly wrong, but that explains what I want to do. After the `swap` statement I'd like `ps` to contain:

- `{ "triangle", 0 }`
- `{ "x", 3 }`
- `{ "square", 2 }`
- `{ "circle", 3 }`

And `xbox` to contain:

- `{ "y", 0 }`
- `{ "a", 1 }`
- `{ "b", 2 }`
- `{ "cross", 1 }`

I expect there is a good way to do this with C++11's move syntax, but if possible I'd like an answer that also describes how to accomplish this on C++03.

Comment: You are not swapping "cross" with "x". You are moving "cross" from ps to xbox, and "x" from xbox to ps. They are two unrelated operations.

Comment: @NeilKirk Right that's why I say in the question "The swap statement is clearly wrong, but that explains what I want to do." Moving the elements to the opposite `map` is what I'm trying to do, as is explained by what I want the resulting `map`s to look like.

Comment: I don't know any way. I wouldn't worry about it unless it really a performance issue. In which case you might find that a flat map (data structure exists in boost I believe) could be even faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` is implemented as an ordered tree.

You cannot simply replace a key with a new key as it might have to be placed on a different location in the tree. Consequently, you cannot swap.

Delete an re-insert the k-v pairs manually.

<sub>(As a sidenote: you haven't even told us what happens with the values...)</sub>

Comment: Ugh, that's what I was doing, but it's sooo ugly. I'll add values to the question.

Comment: It would be nice though, if one could move a map element to another map without having to copy the key (the value can be moved easily).